Is Paul Speaking about the same "body" in 1 Cor 15:35-38, Rm 6:6-12, and Phil 3:10-21?
When Paul made the following statements it appears that He had in His mind the same concepts, and was only expressing them differently in His letters to the various churches.
Was He, in all these cases referring to corruption putting on incorruption?

1Co 15:35 ¶ But some man will say, How are the dead raised up? and with what body do they come?


Ro 6:6 (WNT) This we know--that our old self was nailed to the cross with Him, in order that our sinful nature might be deprived of its power, so that we should no longer be the slaves of sin;


Ro 6:6 (KJV) Knowing this, that our old man is crucified with him, that the body of sin might be destroyed, that henceforth we should not serve sin.


Php 3:21 Who shall change our vile body, that it may be fashioned like unto his glorious body, according to the working whereby he is able even to subdue all things unto himself.

Since Paul wrote that to be absent from the body is to be present with the Lord, I feel that His statements in the 3 referenced sections of scripture all refer to the Body or dwelling we possess during this lifetime.

2Co 5:6 Therefore we are always confident, knowing that, whilst we are at home in the body, we are absent from the Lord:

My thinking along these lines is supported by my understanding of Paul's reference to His students as having already been resurrected or experiencing the resurrection in Colossians 3:1.

Col 3:1 ¶ If ye then be risen with Christ, seek those things which are above, where Christ sitteth on the right hand of God.

I understand that in Dreams and visions, people who had previously died were recognized, but we are not in those cases told specifically that they had bodies.
It seems to me that Paul summarized His thinking along these lines in the following 2 verses in His Second Letter to the Corinthians.

2Co 4:10 Always bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus, that the life also of Jesus might be made manifest in our body.
11 For we which live are alway delivered unto death for Jesus' sake, that the life also of Jesus might be made manifest in our mortal flesh.


"I feel that His statements in the 3 referenced sections of scripture all refer to the Body or dwelling we possess during this lifetime." — Can you cite examples of what makes you think that other people believe differently?

The Rapture" theory" (which I disagree with) suggests that the reference in 1 Cor 15 refers to a Body of some type after physical death. A question that a Pentecostal Brother asked me prompted me to think along these lines.

I also did a video on this today.https://rumble.com/v57l585--corinthians-chapter-15.html
